# How to freeze a row in a Grid element

Tags: silverlight, grid

Is it possible to freeze the top most row within a Silverlight Grid (not DataGrid) element? If so, could someone provide an example of how this can be done?

Thanks,

Xam

Comment: Freeze, like in Excel (scroll freeze)? Or Freeze as in make it so that the row is fixed in size despite resize?

Comment: Freeze as in Excel (scroll freeze).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following structure:

In XAML define:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <Grid Margin="8">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="77.958"/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <ScrollViewer Margin="8,0,8,8" Grid.Row="1" Height="332.042" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
            <Grid Height="524" Width="592" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="#FF00DCD7"/>
        </ScrollViewer>
        <Grid Background="#FF8D0000"/>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

It'll look like this:

[image: Screenshot]

The maroon part is *frozen* in the sense that as you scroll, it will not move.

Comment: Thanks Gleno. This isn't exactly what I had in mind, but given how composition works it is probably the only way to achieve anything close to what I'm after.